# Getting "[-32000] Server error: Wrong response for transaction status query"

Tags: nearprotocol

What does `[-32000] Server error: Wrong response for transaction status query` error mean?

It's a bit unexpected that a server complains about wrong *response*. Isn't response generated by a server itself?

Answer (score 0):

It means the client returns the wrong response to the rpc server, which in general should not happen but right now we have some bugs there. Do you think there is a less confusing way to present the error message?

Comment: "client returns the wrong response to the rpc server" this doesn't make sense to me. Usually it's client sending request and getting response from server, not vice versa.

Errors should use language that makes sense outside of nearcore internals.

Comment: By client I meant client inside nearcore, which is the class that basically handles all the internal logic. I don't think it can make sense outside of nearcore. So probably I'll change to something like "internal server error"